# Recover from deleted Grub_Bios partition?

Tags: boot-repair

Hello while configuring my partition using g parted i had to deleted grub_bios because it was in the middle of free space, i ran boot repair but i couldn't boot into Ubuntu after restart here is my URL from boot repair
http://paste.ubuntu.com/16763016/

Comment: You can install an extra copy of (any contemporary) Ubuntu to an USB-stick .... and the boot from USB ... into the new copy of Ubuntu ,,, and run `$ sudo update-grub` ... and like `$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda/` ( if that's where your missing grub is supposed to be.) Then you should be able to do a normal start-up to e.g. your previous Ubuntu.

Comment: Create a new `grub_bios` partition. It is needed when you use GPT with bios.

Comment: Your Windows is installed in UEFI boot mode. May be better to boot Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. Boot-Repair can convert BIOS install to UEFI install, by uninstalling grub-pc(BIOS) and installing grub-efi-amd64(UEFI) and changing some settings. Just to be sure to boot flash drive in UEFI mode. Shows install with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use gparted to create a new bios_grub partition, if testdisk does not find the old one. Most partition tools see a bios_grub as an issue since it is unformatted. You will not be able to work on the partitions you have mounted with gparted, but should be able to create a partition in the unallocated space. Otherwise you will have to use a liveCD, create partition and reinstall grub from liveCD.

If using gpt with BIOS create a 1MB bios_grub partition with no format. I used gparted and selected gpt under device, advanced & select gpt over msdos(MBR) default partitioning....

You can set bios_grub flag in gparted (right click flags) & no format

In GPT fdisk (gdisk), give bios_grub a type code of EF02.
Or with terminal - see man parted:

```
sudo parted /dev/sda set <partition_number> boot on
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Answer (score 0):

The MBR is the first sector of the disk and doesn't belong to any partition, so you can't delete it. You can delete the bootloader in it, but not the MBR itself.
Try this,

```
sudo parted /dev/sda unit MiB print
```